# Elasticsearch index policy creation best practice/performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, indexing, sharding

I am designing a search system based on ElasticSearch, after reading a lot I have seen that some systems such as logs use a policy of multiple indexes to save the same content, similar to `mylogs-12-02-2020` and are creating an index by day, then to search, they perform the searches in all the indices that comply with the `mylogs- * pattern`, each of those indices has its primary shards and replicas.
My question would be regarding the performance of the searches, which would be more performant to look at an index of 5 million documents, with n shards or look for 50 indexes of 100,000 documents. Does anyone have any experience with the best practice to follow?

I am assuming that my system will have an approximate growth of 200,000 documents per day.

What is the best practice, separate in multiple indexes or have a single index with several primary shards in different nodes (so that they do not compete for the same resources when searching / indexing)?

When doing a search on `mylogs-* elastic` does it parallel to the indexes and within each index in its shards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an Elasticsearch index has 5 primary shards and 1 replica for each. But the problem is default configurations are not suitable for every use case.

Shard size is quite critical for search queries. If there would be too many shards that are assigned to an index, Lucene segments would be small which causes an increase in overhead. Lots of small shards would also reduce query throughput when multiple queries are made simultaneously. On the other hand, too large shards cause a decrease in search performance and longer recovery time from failure. Therefore, **it is suggested by Elasticsearch that one shard’s size should be around 20 to 40 GB.**

Keep in mind it is the shard that acts as a separate search engine in itself, not the index. indices are a type of data organization mechanism, allowing the user to partition data a certain way. that is all!

For further details [read this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-elasticsearch-for-better-search-pe).

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch default configuration given by @Umar is old and starting with 7.0 ES latest major version, **Primary shards reduced to 1**, you can check this in ES [official breaking changes announcement](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_indices_changes).

Nobody can design the perfect ES index with optimal no of shards and replicas and required continuous fine-tuning over the period. Some factors which affect the design consideration.

1. Read or Write-heavy system.
2. Time-based indices(like your log searches) where normally searches happen on more recent logs or e-commerce product catalog or website search where you can't divide indices into time-based data.
3. ES cluster(multi-tenant vs dedicated to single index).

Above are just a few samples and I can go can give 100s of other factors, which you can consider while designing your ES index configuration. **But the idea is to start with more crucial params first(like changing primary shards requires re-indexing) also consider the near-future growth and fine-tune later on based on current system performance.**

I would strongly suggest you go through [my detailed blog](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-search-latency-burst-of-search-traffic-guide/) which would answer your questions about(searching in one index with more docs than searching in more indices/shards with fewer docs) in detail through a real-world case study.

**The above blog also explains the ES decision to change the longtime default primary shards from 5 to 1.**

### Answer to your below question:

Question: When doing a search on `mylogs-* elastic` does it parallel to the indexes and within each index in its shards?

Answer: Yes, ES has distributed architecture and as ES index is made of Lucene shard which is a full-blown search engine, **Every ES query would be executed by multiple threads in parallel if it needs to hit multiple shards(whether of same index or multiple indices), Given threads are free**, otherwise once a thread finish, it would be then be used to query another shard. this is why ES is much faster like other distributed systems.