# Elasticsearch 7.5.2 cluster is creating only one shard for an index by default

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, elasticsearch-7

I have a newly setup Elasticsearch 7.5.2 cluster. When I create an index, only one shard is created default for it.

**My cluster strategy is as below:**

```
Total Nodes: 5
--------------
Node 1 & Node 2 - Master Only
Node 3          - Master & Data Node
Node 4 & Node 5 - Data Only
```

Could not find any cluster setting that is restricting the shards for index creation.
[image]
Is the issue with cluster strategy or am I missing any settings here?.

Please help me to find the the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier Elasticsearch had default number of primary shards to 5, which is changed from Elasticsearch 7.X, which you are using, hence you are seeing just 1 primary shard.

[Elasticsearch link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_indices_changes) for this change and more info on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60358888/4039431) SO answer.

Apart from API which is applicable on a particular index, which @Kamal already mentioned, **you can specify this setting in your `elasticsearch.yml`, which would be effective on every index created until you override using the API call.**

Config to add in your `elasticsearch.yml`

```
index.number_of_shards: {your desired number of shards}
```

Note: This is for primary shards that can't be changed dynamically, so be cautious of setting this, Unlike `the number of replicas` which can be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Post version 7, Elasticsearch by default creates index with shard size 1 as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-settings)

You can always specify the index shard using the below settings, while creating the index.

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 5
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!